# How to deploy Juju Services Programmatically?

Tags: server, juju

How to deploy Juju services Programmatically . Is there any API available to do the same?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a websocket-based Juju API. You can use it from Go directly (see http://godoc.org/launchpad.net/juju-core/state/api), or you can use [Juju Deployer](https://launchpad.net/juju-deployer) Python wrapper around the API. It supports stack-like simple and complex scripted deployments.

The best way will be to get the source locally with `bzr branch lp:juju-deployer` and then see the README file with instructions how to use it. You might build an up-to-date Sphinx documentation by going into the **doc/** directory and running `make singlehtml` (or your preferred format - run `make` to see a list of supported targets).